# Windows universal app and hot keys

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, hotkeys

I create windows universal app. I want to add shortcuts to AppBarButton. Is it possible? I did not find anything about it on the network.

Comment: Please clarify a bit: from what I understood, you want to add `AppBarButton`s to your `AppBar`, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question. This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868246.aspx)  and this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868161(v=win.10).aspx#keyboard_shortcuts) help me. If there is no control input can be used this code:

```
// Listen to the window directly so focus isn't required
Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated +=
       CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;

Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += this.CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
```

This is [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics) used AcceleratorKeyActivated .